# Problema con decimales y porcentajes en mysql

Tags: mysql

Muy buenas, antes de nada os pongo en situación:

Tengo la siguiente tabla (t_operaciones) en mysql:

- Campo: fk_afiliado (Entero) | Ej: 1
- Campo: importe (Decimal) | Ej: 225.20
- Campo: comision_afi (Entero) | Ej: 10

Necesito mostrar la suma de las comisiones de todas las operaciones de un determinado usuario, para ello realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT SUM(importe/comision_afi*100) as importeCom FROM `t_operaciones` WHERE fk_afiliado=1
```

El resultado que devuelve es correcto, pero no diferencia los decimales, por lo que lo muestra como un entero con los decimales sin separación, es decir, siguiendo el ejemplo indicado en la tabla, muestra 2252 en lugar de mostrar 22.52

¿Cómo podría solventarlo?

Gracias de antemano.
un saludo

Comment: Tienes mal el calculo  debería ser `SUM(importe*comision_afi/100)`

Comment: Solucionado!! Muchísimas gracias!!